# How to retrieve the value of a hashmap key from firebase realtime in kotlin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap, key

How do I get the key back
"-Mz_F2UIux3rtKhZqtJw" from a recyclerview and delete it in kotlin?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h76eD.jpg

```
   {
  "postinfo" : {
    "-Mz_F2UIux3rtKhZqtJw" : {
      "description" : "vvv",
      "fileName" : "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2F20211123_123211.jpg",
      "fileUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/database-31ad2.appspot.com/o/files%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.externalstorage.documents%2Fdocument%2Fprimary%253ADCIM%252FCamera%252F20211123_123211.jpg?alt=media&token=081badb6-c84c-46ee-a57a-7aa67b6896f4",
      "imageName" : "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2F20211123_102056.jpg",
      "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/database-31ad2.appspot.com/o/images%2Fcontent%3A%2Fcom.android.externalstorage.documents%2Fdocument%2Fprimary%253ADCIM%252FCamera%252F20211123_102056.jpg?alt=media&token=4e584b77-3504-4c20-957f-4f3810a79db6",
      "title" : "bbb",
      "userid" : "4ylJ9l4icSZnfuY4Ts96jL8hzBJ3",
      "username" : "bbb"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Firebase is quite well documented and there are hundreds of tutorials out there. Can you show what you tried already based on those resources?

Comment: So what exactly would you like to achieve? Do you want to read the entire node? If yes, do you already know that pushed `-Mz_F2UIux3rtKhZqtJw` ID?